# CSS & JS - Remove modal when clicked on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Currently I am making my own modal for my system. When you click on the name of a package the modal popups up and displays. I added some JQuery that is supposed to remove the modal when clicked on the background. It does that but also when I click on the modal itself it hides.

I tried adding z-index 3 to the parent and z-index 4 to the modal but that does not work. How can I make it so that if clicked on the background, the modal disappears but when clicked on the modal itself it does nothing and people can just interact normally with the modal?

I have a small illustration

[image]

The popups are appended to a parent using Ajax (See below)

```js
<div class="container-fluid pt-5 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>{{ __('Packages') }}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row my-5">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="package-loading" class="text-center">
                    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x color-primary"></i>
                </div>
                <p id="package-error" class="text-danger" style="display: none"></p>
                <div id="packages-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-list">

    </div>

    <script>
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            url: 'https://www.rainierlaansite.test/api/packages/get',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#package-loading').fadeOut();
                let wrapper = $("#packages-wrapper");
                let popup_list = $('.popup-list');
                let popup = 'popup-id';

                if(data == null) {
                    console.log('lol')
                }
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    let el = data[index];
                    wrapper.append(
                        '<div class="row my-4" data-id='+ el.id +'>' +
                            '<div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center"><i class="far fa-archive fa-2x"></i></div>' +
                            '<div class="col-6">' +
                                '<a href="#" class="popup" data-popup-id="'+ el.id +'"><h6 class="m-0">'+ el.name +'</h6></a>' +
                                '<p class="m-0 sub-text">'+ el.description +'</p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">' +
                                '<a href="#" id="download_package" class="badge badge-pill badge-light popup '+ (el.price == 0 ? 'badge-primary': 'badge-light') +'" style="font-size: 14px;" data-popup-id="'+ el.id +'">' + (el.price == 0 ? 'Download': '$ ' + el.price) +'</a>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' + '<hr>'
                    );
                    popup_list.append(
                        '<div class="package-popup shadow popup-'+ el.id +'">' +
                            '<div class="package-popup-dialog">' +
                                '<div class="package-popup-content">' +
                                    '<div class="row">' +
                                        '<div class="col-2">' +
                                            '<div class="row">' +
                                                '<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">' +
                                                    '<i class="far fa-archive fa-3x"></i>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="col-7">' +
                                            '<div class="row">' +
                                                '<div class="col-12">' +
                                                    '<h4 class="m-0">' + el.name + '</h4>' +
                                                    '<p class="sub-text">' + el.creator + '</p>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="col-3 text-center">' +
                                            '<h4><a href="#" id="download_package" class="badge badge-pill '+ (el.price == 0 ? 'badge-primary': 'badge-light') +'">' +
                                                (el.price == 0 ? 'Download': '$ ' + el.price) +
                                            '</a></h4>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="offset-2 col-7">\n' +
                                            '<div class="rating">\n' +
                                                '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i></span>' +
                                                '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i></span>' +
                                                '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i></span>' +
                                                '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i></span>' +
                                                '<span><i class="fas fa-star grey"></i></span>' +
                                                '<small><a href="">· Uit 300 beoordelingen</a></small>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                            '<small>Nog geen beoordelingen</small>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="col-3 text-center">'+
                                            '<i class="far fa-download"></i> ' + el.downloads +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="row my-5">' +
                                        '<div class="col-12">' +
                                            '<nav>' +
                                                '<div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">' +
                                                    '<a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Details</a>' +
                                                    '<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Reviews</a>' +
                                                    '<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Version history</a>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                            '</nav>' +
                                            '<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">' +
                                                '<div class="tab-pane fade show active py-4" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">' +
                                                    '<p>' + el.description + '</p>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                                '<div class="tab-pane fade py-4" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">' +
                                                    'Dit is twee tekst' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                                '<div class="tab-pane fade py-4" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">' +
                                                    'Dit is tekst 3' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                });

                $('.popup').on('click', function () {
                    if($(this).data(popup)) {
                        let item = $('.popup-' + $(this).data(popup));
                        item.addClass('show');
                        $(item).on('click', function() {
                            item.removeClass('show');
                            console.log('ik klik op de achtergrond');
                        })
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $('#package-error').fadeIn().text("Unfortunately there was an error retrieving the packages");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

*HTML*

*SASS*

```css
.package-popup
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    display: none
    overflow: hidden
    background-color: $primary_background_transparent
    z-index: 3
    .package-popup-dialog
        max-width: 960px
        position: relative
        margin: auto
        top: 100px
        background-color: $color-white
        border-radius: 16px
        padding: 3rem
        z-index: 4
        pointer-events: none
        .package-popup-content
            position: relative
            pointer-events: auto
            display: flex
            flex-direction: column
```

Comment: Are the popups children of the "background"s?  If so, click events bubble.  Which could possibly explain why clicking on the modal also triggers the click logic on the background.

Comment: The popups are in a parent class called `popup-list` because I need to append them somewhere because of the Ajax. I don't believe I can append them in my file without a parent class using javascript

Comment: I had a hard time understanding your question. First you don't provide the HTML code, but the script that creates the code. If you provided the HTML would be much easier (Inspect element: Copy outerHTML). Also a important piece of css is missing: `.show {display: block}`, and your condition to show the popup will fail if id is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the click event target:

```
$(item).on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("shadow")) {
    // Close dialog
  }
}
```

Remove the `pointer-events: none` from the css to make it work